# Disable TLS 1.2 in Linux using any of the chrome /firefox

Tags: linux, ssl

I want to disable TLS 1.2 version of a virtual machine (linux). I was wondering if there are any commands to disable it . 
In windows we usually go to settings>Advaced settings>change proxy settings>advanced  in the google chrome , in advanced tab I just disable the radio button. But in case of linux I'm not able to find any settings related to TLS .

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `SSLProtocol` is an Apache directive, not a command. What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: I want to disable TLS 1.2 , because  my setup supports TLS 1.2 but i want to try loading the web page disabling TLS 1.2 .In windows i was able to do it as it is simple in windows but I don't know how to disable it in LINUX

Comment: I want to load a webpage in any version other than TLS 1.2 in a linux system .

Answer (score 2):

There is no general setting system wide setting. But there might be settings specific for each browser. For Chrome this might be `--tls-version-max` as described [in the list of command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). For Firefox this would be `security.tls.version.max` as described [at mozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.tls.version.*).

Apart from that: if you are trying restricting the best version offered by a browser to work around some problem then you are probably doing it the wrong way.